# Retrieve a list of files located at a URL with filenames matching a known pattern

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

There is a URL where a colleague has set up a large number of files for me to download,

```
url = "http://www.some.url.edu/some/dirname/"
```

Inside this directory, there are a large number of files with different filename patterns that are known to me in advance, e.g., "subvol1_file1.tar.gz", "subvol1_file2.tar.gz", etc. I am going to selectively download these files based on their filename patterns using fnmatch.

What I need is a simple list or generator of *all* filenames located in *dirname*. Is there a simple way to use, for example, BeautifulSoup or urllib2 to retrieve such a list?

Once I have the list/iterable, let's call it **filename_sequence**, I plan to download the files with a pattern *filepat* with the following pseudocode:

```
filename_sequence = code_needed
filepat = "*my.pattern*"
import os, fnmatch
for basename in fnmatch.filter(filename_sequence, filepat):
    os.system("wget "+os.path.join(url, basename))
```

Comment: Could you show the HTML representation of the directory with filenames? Thanks.

Comment: http://www.some.url.edu/some/dirname/ contains links to all available resources, yes. I do not have a list in advance of all available resources. I do, however, have a known string that is a *prefix* for any filename of interest.

Comment: `filename_sequence = [url + fn for fn in all_filenames]`?

Comment: I do not know *all_filenames* in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is applicable in your case, but you can apply a regular expression pattern on the `href` attribute values:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"subvol1_file\d+\.tar\.gz")
links = [a["href"] for a in soup.find_all("a", href=pattern)]
```